# Access raw_post_data in django test client

Tags: django, json, django-views

The title pretty much says it all:  I use raw_post_data in a couple of views, and thus I need the test client to properly grant access to it.

I have copied the raw_post_data string, from a mock request, passed it to json.loads(), and then used the resulting dict as the POST data for the test client.  Then, I set the content type to "application/json" - this causes raw_post_data to appear, but it is not the same raw_post_data as the mock request.

Comment: Could you post the (differences between the) data that appears and the request you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 4):

When you change the content type in the test client, the data parameter is not parsed as a dictionary anymore but sent directly. Try copyin your JSON string directly as the data parameter to your post request, you should receive it in raw_post_data in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to follow the steps as below:
    1. set the data attribute to your *string*. 
    2. then set the *content_type* attribute to *application/octet-stream*.

```
    payload = {'k1':'v1'}
    data = json.dumps(payload)
    response = self.client.post(url, data=data, content_type='application/octet-stream', **self.auth_headers)
```

Comment: This worked like charm. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/test/client/